# Programatically check if there is a configuration profile installed or not on an iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, configuration-files

I need to develop an application that programatically checks if there is a configuration profile (called "X", for example) installed on the phone or not.

I tried the solution already on this [link](http://alex.tapmania.org/2011/09/check_conf_prof_is_installed_ios.html)  but it didn't work. I also posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291846/unable-to-check-if-a-configuration-profile-exists-on-the-iphone-objective-c) already related to this solution, but there has been no answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is very hard to do. If you are asking in the context of an MDM solution then your app on the device could ask the server for what is installed (assuming you, or your company, develop both the MDM-side and the app on the device). If your app needs to find out by itself then the only way to do this is if your app is an in-house app:
- run it as a VOIP app so it can run regularly in the background
- monitor the iOS kernel messages via an asl_queue for messages relating to a profile getting installed or deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your response! what we have is not a full MDM solution (currently under development) . what we have is a limited solution that enables remote wipe and forcing the user to have a phone passcode. the app I am developing is an in-house app . if this is the only solution then I have no choice but doing it like the VOIP apps . can you suggest a tutorial or something that can show me how to do that ... and I agree with you it is very hard and very few online resources are out there to solve this issue ...

Comment: @onnoweb Dude i have the problem and i need your MDM solution can u explain me clearly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236305/detecting-ios-app-with-app-lock-mdm-profile