# Detecting iOS app with app lock MDM profile

Tags: ios, mdm

We are doing an app where we apply app lock to the app.we need to check if the app lock profile is already installed or not.is there a way to check if it is already installed in the app.We need to do this as because when  a new version of app is installed in device then app lock profile cannot be added to the new app as it is already installed in the older app.is there a way to detect if app lock is installed in the app or not programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

IOS MDM has a command "Profile list". It will enumerate all profiles installed on the device and return it to the server.

You should send this command and check the return dictionary to see whether your app lock profile is in there.

Check MDM Protocol reference guide for details.

Comment: Can u give me some reference and guides where i can implement them programmatically

Comment: How do you install app lock profile? Do you have MDM server? Is it implemented by you or some 3rd party vendor (and you are using it just to deliver profiles)? Do you have MDM protocol documentation? Have you read about Profile list command?

Comment: my answer is yes for all your questions expect for the last one.

Comment: I am not sure which server do you use. There is a chance that you server doesn't have ProfileList command at all or even if you have it, I am not sure how do you plan to integrate in it conditional logic. If you have some complex logic, you will need to be able to modify your MDM server source code. I would recommend to read MDM protocol documentaion about ProfileList command. If you can send this command and parse the response, it's trivial to do conditional logic based on that.